# How to get and count all the enabled input fields of a form in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to get total number of input fields which are enable and also those which are filled and non-empty.

Comment: `$('input[type="text"]:not(:disabled)').length` try this.

Comment: Jai's selector fixed for non empty fields: `$('input[type="text"]:not(:disabled)').filter(function(){return $(this).val()!="";});`

Comment: thanks alot.. and what about empty fields, can we do it as  $('input[type="text"]:(:empty)').length

Comment: @Insomania try from Banana as in comment. like `$('input[type="text"]:not(:disabled)').filter(function(){return $(this).val()=="";}).length;`

Comment: @Insomania to get the empty fields change the `.val()!=""` to `.val()==""`

Comment: thanks to all of you guys, for your help.... "stackoverflow" such a real guide for developers...  :) :)

Comment: also you can use trimming to exclude inputs that contain spaces without text `$('input[type="text"]:not(:disabled)').filter(function(){return $.trim($(this).val())!="";});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[type="text"]:enabled').filter(function(){return $(this).val()=="";}).length;
```